# GDAL's SetProjection() produces error: (Error) GDAL failure (1) missing [

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to compute a CHM (Canopy Height Model) using GDAL for Python.

```
A_TIF = os.getcwd() + xyzlocation + folder + "\\dtm.tif"
B_TIF = os.getcwd() + xyzlocation + folder + "\\dsm.tif"
OUT_TIF = os.getcwd() + xyzlocation + folder + "\\chm.tif"

ds1 = gdal.Open(A_TIF, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
ds2 = gdal.Open(B_TIF, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)

arr1 = ds1.ReadAsArray()
arr2 = ds2.ReadAsArray()

# subtract every value from both rasters
result = np.subtract(arr2, arr1)

# get attributes from input raster 1 and set them to the output raster
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
output = driver.Create(OUT_TIF, arr1.shape[1], arr1.shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
output.SetGeoTransform(ds1.GetGeoTransform())
output.SetProjection("EPSG:3067") # (Error) GDAL failure (1) missing [

output.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(result)
```

The line mentioned above produces an error:

> (Error) GDAL failure (1) missing [

Why is this?

---

Also, this code may fail to produce the CHM (results in 1KB file). But this is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from osgeo import osr
proj = osr.SpatialReference()
proj.ImportFromEPSG(3067)
output.SetProjection(proj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Yjelza's answer, the `SetProjection()` method takes a string as its argument and not a `SpatialReference` object. You have to call the `ExportToWkt()` method on the object.

```py
from osgeo import osr
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(3067)
output.SetProjection(sr.ExportToWkt())
```

If you want to take the projection of one of the input rasters it would be as simple as you did by setting the GeoTransform.

```py
output.SetProjection(ds1.GetProjection())
```

Note that if you are trying to use a different projection that the one `ds1` has, the GeoTransform object won't work because it has the raster origin coordinates in another spatial reference.

---

Also, it is possible that running your script results in a 1KB file because you are not closing the file at the end of the script.

Try adding the following line at the end:

```py
output = None
```

Comment: Good spot, I forgot to ExportToWkt! But I would suggest output = None instead of del, it helps with properly closing the dataset in the gdal bindings

Comment: @Yjelza Didn't know there was a difference between using `del` and setting it to `None`. Will keep that in mind!